# form fields display cached values

Tags: zend-framework, zend-session

My `policyInfoAction` redirects my form to `clientInfoAction`. It stores the empty field errors and then validates the fields in the session variables and redirects it to the `client-info` page if it contains errors.
It works fine. But the problem is the next time I hit the `/client-info` page in a new tab it shows the form values in the fields. I have to hit the refresh page to clear it out. I do not want it to display cached data when I open the link in a new tab. What should I do?

```
public function clientInfoAction(){
    //If there are some errors and some valid fields, display the valid fields
    $client=$this->session->client;
    $state=$this->session->state;
    unset($this->session->client, $this->session->state); // delete from the 

    // assign the values to the view
    $this->view->client = $client;
    $this->view->state  = $state;
}
```

Here is my view:

```
<form action ="/pdp/policy-info/" method='post'">

    <label for="client_name">Client Name:  </label>
    <input type="text" name="client_name" id="client_name">
    <?php if (!empty($this->client_error)) echo "<font size='2' color ='#C11B17'>".$this->client_error."</font>"; ?>
    <br><br>

    <label for="state">State: </label>
    <select name="state" id='state'>
        <option id='state' value="" selected="selected"></option>
```

Comment: That sounds like something your browser is doing not your application.

Comment: Are you saying that this happens after a roundtrip?